# Export Python with librarieS?

Tags: python

How do I export Python with the libraries used? It seems like a hassle to get people to install not only Python but the libraries needed to run the code.

I'm using Python 3.4 so I can't use Py2Exe, how do I include the libraries in a folder to use locally without installing them to the system?

Comment: Create a setup script and put the name of the libs in dependencies, or copy all the libs to a libs folder in your project and add that folder to the path before the imports.

Comment: What code do I use before the imports?

Comment: `os.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net with python 3...

Comment: Does this work for Windows .exe?

Comment: Yes, apparently. http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html (but I've only used it on Linux).